# What does ⊥ mean in a consensus protocol?

Tags: protocols, consensus

I am reading Ben Or's algorithm and I want know the meaning of  bp := ⊥ in line 7?Here is the whole algorithm

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you got downvoted, but the best reason I can guess is that this may be better suited for math.stackexchange.com. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot for an explanation of the symbol and this page for some additional information to the protocol: http://www.nada.kth.se/kurser/kth/2D5340/wwwbook/node17.html

I'm not familiar with Ben Or's algorithm, but the page linked above seems to have a reasonable explanation for the use of the symbol:

> In order to get an intuition of how randomization is used, suppose
>   that the inputs are split in half; half of them being zeroes and half
>   of them being ones. In this case, every process will set its b-value
>   to ⊥ (line 7). Since all b-values are ⊥, each process will
>   set the next a-value at random. With high probability, about half of
>   the new a-values will be zeroes and about half will be ones. Which
>   again will force a random determination of all new a-values, and so
>   on.

Following the logic, `bp := ⊥` indicates that *bp* is undecided.